# How ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap); takes bitmap object as an argument?

Tags: android, android-canvas

In the following code snippet how are the parameters of Canvas's drawCircle applied to mBitmap which is passed as an argument to setImageBitmap..?

```
  mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300,600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
  mCanvas.drawCircle(110,120,60,mpaint);
  mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is provided by the documentation for the `Canvas` constructor that takes a Bitmap.

> public Canvas (Bitmap bitmap)
>
> Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into. The bitmap
>   must be mutable.
>
> The initial target density of the canvas is the same as the given
>   bitmap's density.

When you create a `Canvas` using the constructor that takes a `Bitmap`, all drawing operations performed on that canvas are done directly into the bitmap.

Comment: Thank you. can you describe this with an simple example if possible?